# The upgrade to PHP 7.3 broke code that previously worked, how to solve?

Tags: php, wordpress, array-merge

My WordPress site worked fine until a PHP update, I didn't update the version of the online site, but the one I work on local server for experiments detected the following problem.

The message that appears is:

> "Warning: array_merge(): Argument #19 is not an array in C:....php on line 1004"

It seems to happen in the array_merge function.

```
<?php

$resume = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => array('post', 'events'),
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'custom_filter',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'location_latitude',
            ),
        ),
    )
);

foreach ($resume as $post) {
    $meta[] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_category', true);
}

$oneDimensionalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $meta); // Problem - line 1004 // 

$unique = array_unique($oneDimensionalArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < (is_array($oneDimensionalArray) ? count($oneDimensionalArray) : 0); $i++) {
    if (!in_array($oneDimensionalArray[$i], $unique)) {
        $unique[] = $oneDimensionalArray[$i];
    }
}

sort($unique);  /* Sort array by value alphabetically */

foreach ($unique as $value) {
    $resume2 = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => array('post', 'estabelecimentos', 'eventos', 'parceiros', 'noticias'),
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'custom_category',
                    'value' => $value,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'location_latitude',
                ),
            ),
        )
    );

    $count = count($resume2);

    ?>

    <label title="<?php echo $value; ?>&nbsp;(<?php echo $count; ?>)"><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox"
                                                                             data-value="<?php echo $value; ?>"
                                                                             name="category[]"
                                                                             value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?>
        <span>&nbsp;(<?php echo $count; ?>)</span></input></label>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It looks like `$meta` in not array, try to check what is in this variable.

Answer (score 0):

What PHP version did you use before?

I know this answer is not solving the problem, but maybe it will help you a little.

Look if you can use xdebug (I use it with PHPstorm) with your code program, you can easly add breakpoints in your code and look step by step what happens.

Maybe you can also add

```
vardump($meta);
exit;
```

before the error to see what $meta exactly contains. Also try to dump and exit other variables before that.

Maybe you can also try to set the `$oneDimensionalArray = [];` before the merge function.